# CSS When should I use the style attribute?

Tags: html, css, styles, coding-style

Hello i'm creating a webpage from scratch and I'm running into a problem

I know using the style tag is not very good, but would it be in this case okay to use? or maybe is there a better way of doing it?

let's say I have this CSS

```
.group-box {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgba(30,30,30);
    padding: 15px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(10,136,0, 0.2);
}
```

and I have

```
<div class="groupbox"></div>
```

but now let's say I wanted to make my groupbox bigger for one-time use, is it okay to do?

```
<div class="groupbox" style="height: 300px;"></div>
```

or should I just make a whole separate class like a small-groupbox and a big-groupbox with all the same properties, just different heights values? I'm leaning more towards the style attribute. But maybe there is a better way?

**I am wondering what the CSS "coding" standard would say about this question. my question is subjective, but I want to know what most others who are more experienced at CSS would do in my situation.**

Thanks

Comment: This one Probably might help you: https://www.javatpoint.com/types-of-css

Comment: @YashChitroda I understand the differences, I am wondering what the CSS "coding" standard would say about this question. my question is subjective, but I want to know what most others who are more experienced at CSS would do in my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It totally depends on ‘your situation’. In particular considering maintainability/readability for future developers. There can be no one right answer. Both methods are allowed by the standard.

The thing to watch if using classes is cascading/specificity which you can be confident are dealt with if using style.

But set against that is the ability in a stylesheet to use class names which have meaning. And there is true separation between styling and semantics, the styling not being ‘buried’ amongst HTML. You can also group settings so the maintainer isn’t hunting through many lines of code to find changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both, however, it's always best practice to use external CSS, and class than inline-CSS, however if it's very few line, then it'll not affect the performance much.